# Superior and lower extrem of f(x,y)

Tags: calculus, analysis

How can I find the supremum and infimum of a function in two variables?
This is an example: $f(x,y) = (x^2 - 1)^2 \mathop{\rm sgn}(y)$
Evidently the domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and Now? How can I resolve the exercise?

Thank You and Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Depends.

Your example: $(x^2-1)^2$ has no upper bound, so for $y < 0$, $f$ has no lower bound, for $y>0$, $f$ has no upper bound. Hence 
$$\inf_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2}f(x,y) = -\infty \text{ and } \sup_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2}f(x,y) = +\infty.$$

There are some standard ways to find infimum and supremum, like finding local extrema via differentiation or if the domain is bounded you can check the boundary for extrema.